# How do you define on which step app has to ask user to sign up?

Tags: login, sign-in

**How to define certain step in the app where user will be asked to sign up?**
If there are requirements, that the daily task manager app design should contain sign up & login. But what if we don't want user to sign up from the first interaction with an app. In such case we have to define on which step ask user to sign up. And I see that in many **to-do apps such as "Any.do",** **"Wunderlist"** there is **sign up screen from the beginning** in a way to sync data throughout all devices straightaway.

Following other strategy I want to give user an opportunity to use the app as simple grocery list without signing him up yet.
Only when user will want to make a note inside subtask/split and manage small tasks/use file-drop capabilities/share task with someone else (**extend grocery list app to a GTD** let's say) I will ask him to sign up. Is it correct way? For people who want to backup tasks to the server from the beginning, I will include this option somewhere in settings of the app, so it would be available, but optional first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to have an optional sign up process from the first screen. And build some triggers inside an application for users who skipped sign up. It might be:
1. Share shopping list with your family (Mandatory)
2. Create new shopping list (Optional)
3. Summary screen on the end of shopping. (Optional)

But those triggers won't interrupt any process.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it make sense. I will follow your advice.